# QGIS saving shapefile wrong utf8 encoding in DBF?

Tags: qgis-2, encoding

I'm using QGIS for some SHP processing.
When I save the file, the DBF utf-8 text encoding is wrong:

Source DBF

```
à0è0ì0ò0ù0  HEX: C3A0 30 C3A8 30 C3AC 30 C3B2 30 C3B9 30
```

Saved DBF

```
Ã 0Ã¨0Ã¬0Ã²0Ã¹ HEX: C383C2A030C383C2A830C383C2AC30C383C2B230C383C2B9
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you know what is the source encoding of your data and choose it when creating a layer.QGIS by default exports vector data in system encoding which doesn't have to be necessarily utf-8.